# Widgets IntentHandler parameters with dynamic options dependent on other parameter's value

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, widgetkit

I'm making an iOS 14 style widget and want to provide some settings in the edit menu. These settings need to have options that change depending on the other setting that's selected.

Simplifying here, but say I have two parameters for my Intent: `drink` and `modifier`.

If Coffee is selected for `drink`, then the `modifier` options should Ice, Sugar, Creamer.
If Soda is selected for `drink`, then the `modifier` options should just be Ice.

This is all fine and I can do something like this in the IntentHandler file:

```
func provideModifierOptionsCollection(for intent: WidgetSettingIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Modifier>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    var modifiers: [Modifier] = []
    if intent.drink?.identifier == "coffee" {
        modifiers = [Modifier(identifier: "ice", display: "Ice"),
                     Modifier(identifier: "sugar", display: "Sugar"),
                     Modifier(identifier: "creamer", display: "Creamer")]
    } else {
        modifiers = [Modifier(identifier: "ice", display: "Ice")]
    }
    let collection = INObjectCollection(items: modifiers)
    completion(collection, nil)
}
```

If I edit the widget now and select Soda, then I only get the Ice modifier, and when I select Coffee, I get the Ice, Sugar, and Creamer modifiers. Great!

However, the problem is that I can select Coffee and Creamer, but when I switch the drink to Soda, the modifier stays on Creamer which is no longer an option.

Is there a way to fix this without having to just use 1 parameter with all 4 combinations?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?
I am facing a similar issue but with dynamic data so your workaround "1 param with all combinations" is not going to do it :)

Comment: @schmidiii no unfortunately I didn't end up finding a solution.